# How can I access the files on my WD Cloud drive?

Tags: linux, external-hard-drive, data-recovery, elementaryos

My WD Cloud drive network card broke.  [I removed the hard drive](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DKoBWOVmbjA) from the WD Cloud enclosure and put it in an external SATA drive housing.  I am now connected to the HD via USB using Elementary OS Linux.  I can navigate the files.  When I navigate to /shares/Brian it tells me "This folder does not belong to you, you don't have permission to view this folder"

How can I view and recover my files?  I'm pretty sure I know the password I used for the WD Cloud drive if that helps at all.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Terminal.
2. navigate to the cloud drive folder.  In my case `/media/brian/{some-GUID}/shares`
3. `sudo chown brian Brian/` (Note brian argument came from `whoami`)
4. `cd Brian/`
5. `ls` (Should now be able to see all files!).  And you can view them in Pantheon's file manager too